# Using Workflow Foundation to define flow of asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have several ASP.net web pages. I want to use Workflow Foundation to define different BPM  Work Flows to run my pages. How can I do that with Windows Workflow Foundation?
It seems to me that workflow foundation is not for web apps. Am I correct?

Comment: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/29992/0/page/2

Comment: What version of WF are you using?  What version of ASP.NET?